# Can I use a plastic water tube as resistance to protect bathing people within a safe voltage?

Tags: safety, leakage-current, water

Suppose home water has a resistivity of 2 Ωm, home electricity is AC 220 V, and human body in shower has a resistance of 1 kΩ.
Then a resistance R = 8.2 kΩ, which is a plastic water pipe of 1.29 m in length and 2 cm inner diameter, would be enough to keep voltage on human body under a safe value of 24 V in an electric leakage in the water heater.
Then why do we still worry about an electric shock in shower, even without any other security measures like grounding or leakage protector?
[image: Circiut graph]

I understand that it would be insanely irresponsible to leave out any other safety measures and I am not going to put it into practice, just wondering if this really can be a serious safety measure, or that I have made some mistakes in my calculation. Since I have never heard of such a safety measure before though it seems so simple and useful.

Comment: 220V/9200ohm is just under 24mA, which won’t feel nice at a bare minimum.

Comment: What if you just earthed the shower head or metal pipe leading to it?

Comment: Why not just run plastic pipe all the way? But the problem is that the water is a conductor. If you are going to be touching the conductor, the insulation around the outside of the conductor is not so beneficial. I wouldn't care to bet my life that the water in my pipes has a conductivity less than "X" under all circumstances.

Comment: Don't. Just don't even go there on electrical safety. Just follow the codes for the jurisdiction you are in.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to safety, you don't try to sketch some resistances on a math sheet, that manage to just get you below unsafe levels of electricity.

Safety is a much more conceptual thing: You engineer stuff in a way, that even the dumbest individual, on their worst of days, during a mains surge would require astronomical bad luck to get in contact with objectionable electricity at all.

Comment: Good point! But do you think this could work as at least one of many plausible safe measures?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what kind of math you did to conclude that that level of resistance would prevent injuries. If we use Ohm's law with the numbers that you provided, we find that the current that the person could be exposed to is

$$\frac{220 \ \mathrm{V}}{8200 \ \Omega + 1000 \ \Omega} \approx 0.025 \ \mathrm{A},$$

which I'm pretty sure is enough current to kill a person taking a shower.

I admit that a length of plastic pipe similar to the one you described *could* prevent injuries, in much the same way that if you carry a chunk of steel in your shirt pocket, then that chunk of steel *could* save your life if someone shoots at you. But using a plastic pipe as a protective insulator in this way is not an approved safety practice.

You don't design safe systems by inventing solutions and then trying to calculate whether or not somebody could get hurt (unless you're a licensed engineer). You design safe systems by finding an appropriate set of safety rules and following all of them.

Comment: I agree with your math. 25 mA can be fatal. "But using a plastic pipe as a protective insulator is not an approved safety practice." Actually it is. In the US we call it non-metallic conduit. The plastic isn't the problem. The conductivity of the water is the problem. If the person and the water were separated by a plastic tube, the person would be protected by the plastic barrier from any electric potential on the other side. I guess you probably know all this. I just felt compelled to comment for the benefit of those who come after.

Comment: @mkeith Yeah, that's true. What I meant was that a plastic pipe is not an approved way of insulating the water in one end of the pipe from the water in the other end of it.

Answer (score 1):

Among other parameters that can vary wildly, skin resistance varies among people. Then there's the fact that wet skin has lower resistance than dry skin. Then there's the fact that water in a shower hits your parts of your body with a mucous membrane like your eyes, mouth, and other...sensitive parts.

The resistivity of materials is also not constant with voltage and can drastically decrease at higher voltages.

Assuming you're talking about centralized electric water heaters, there's also the issue of having installation issues. The plastic tube is something rather distinct and separate from the electric water heater and it would be easy to overlook or outright ignore during installation (maybe you don't want to replace the metal pipes that are already there). If anything you'd be better off building that winding length of insulating pipe directly into the electric water heater itself.

For electric shower heads it just doesn't work because no one is going to want to run extra length of pipe behind the shower head.

Comment: "Among other parameters that can vary wildly, you list 1MOhm for resistance but that seems to be high" – Where did the asker write that? I only see a mention of 1 kOhm, not 1 MOhm.

Comment: @Tanner-reinstateLGBTpeople My bad. I read 1000Ω as 1000MΩ for some reason...and then my brain interpreted that as 1MΩ lol.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re proposing isn’t at all safe. It’s even less safe than a ‘suicide shower’ (heated shower head) which has a ground inside the head itself. More about those here: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jo99U3nVCnA